# groupadd -p Not Recommended?

Tags: command-line, security, password

I have a question about groupadd, specifically with password (-p). It says it is not recommended, "This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes." Can someone give me a broader explanation? How will a user see the password when viewing the processes, and if that is the case why is this used?

Comment: Groupadd has no such option. What platform are you using?

Comment: @schily `shadow-utils`'s [`groupadd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/groupadd.8.html) does.

Comment: The user would see the password by running ps and seeing it as a command line argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *possible* for a user on the system (or a monitoring program that captures `ps` output) to see the password as a parameter to the groupadd process -- if the user or monitor "happens" to run `ps` while the `groupadd` process is running. The risk of that happening is small (the groupadd process will likely finish running fairly quickly), but non-zero.

See an example for yourself with this contrived example; execute these two lines within 10 seconds of each other:

```
$ sh -c "echo groupadd -p password-here > /dev/null; sleep 10" &
$ ps -ef | grep password
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can mitigate this a bit on many platforms by forbiding users to see each other's processes. On Linux this can be done by setting the mount option hidepid=1 (or 2) on /proc, on BSDs you have a sysctl value to do the same thing.

Comment: Excellent and clear response! Also, thanks @user60039 for the tip :D